# How can we decrypt xor cipher that got encrypted again with xor

Tags: python, encryption, xor

I want to decrypt a **binary file** which containes XOR cipher that got encrypted again with XOR (twice), without knowing the key length or the key it self, from a website called [XOR Cracker](https://wiremask.eu/tools/xor-cracker/) my key is probably in length of **3**. How can we make a Python script that will decrypt the XOR cipher without knowing the key?

**I currently have this function, but I can find a way to break the cipher and find the key.**

```
def xor(data, key): 
    return bytearray(a^b for a, b in zip(*map(bytearray, [data, key])))
```

By the way, is text that got encrypted twice with XOR called - [xor-encrypt-xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor%E2%80%93encrypt%E2%80%93xor)?

---

More about [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher)

Comment: Do you think the same key was used both times for the XOR? If so, the file *already decrypted*; that's *how XOR works*. If it was different keys of the same length, then it is the same as if you had XORd *the keys* together, and used the result as the real key.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a general computer-science question, not a programming question and certainly not a Python-specific one.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel There are tons of XOR questions and encryption in general in StackOverflow. I googled it. But they are not answered my question.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm not sure if the same key was used in both times.

Comment: Is your question mostly about the multiple XOR encryption process, or about how to actually go about finding an unknown key? Because those are really unrelated. The first is a very basic detail of XOR encryption (that doing it many times doesn't add much security). The latter is a much large and more complicated topic, and we probably don't know enough about your data and problem to give a huge amount of advice.

Comment: @Blckknght My question is about how to find the key and how to finally decrypt my binary file. Thanks

Comment: So to solve the larger problem (rather than just the part about the multiple keys), you'll really need to do more work up front before we can help you. Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. You're a lot more likely to get an answer if you've already tried solving the problem yourself, and you can be asking about a specific problem that you're running into in your implementation. A big question with no attempted solution, just sounds like "give me the codez" and is likely to be ignored.

Comment: That's part of why I asked about the two-key part of the question, since that's a small enough part of the larger problem that you can reasonably expect to get an answer about just that, without every answer needing to solve the larger cryptanalysis task.

Comment: Xor is commutative, so there isn't just one pair of keys that successfully decrypt the ciphertext. Just assume that only key was used and break the cipher as explained many times ([example](https://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/6)). The second key is then all zeros.